# Hardhat MetaMask Error: Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 31337

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, react, error, raw-transaction

I created a Real-Estate Decentralized Contract and connected it with **Vite-React** using **ethers.js**.

I'm using **Meta Mask** and **HardHat** local network for Hardhat free Ether. I import 5 wallets of **Hardhat** to the **MetaMask** for making transactions.

After compile the contract i copy the contracts abis and on src directory i create a floder abis and past the abis in that folder

I create a component **Home.jsx** and in this component, I create some functions that call the escrow contract function and perform transactions. When I click on any Button (Sell & Approve, Buy, Approve Inspection, Approve & Lend) it open meta mask and when i confirm the transaction it shows the error and failed the transaction. And when i click on any button and the meta mask popup shows for confirmation in that pop up data section i see (Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 31337) this error. And the error which i provided i saw it on chrome console.

Please help me to solve this issue.

**Escrow Contract Link:** https://github.com/huzaafi/Real-Estate-Project/blob/main/contracts/Escrow.sol

**App.jsx Link:** https://github.com/huzaafi/Real-Estate-Project/blob/main/src/App.jsx

**Home.jsx Link:** https://github.com/huzaafi/Real-Estate-Project/blob/main/src/components/Home.jsx

Error:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":1340796751225,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0x02f898827a69028459682f00846a9b4030825d0094dc64a140aa3e981100a9beca4e685f962f0cf6c9884563918244f40000a4e740f7700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c080a0321f3df88f7b6a4c6cf4d23237a233a349186d4f9fcf7e01ee1775c0ade4cfdda0258f6294507b47cec5278a44cf33ba7afaa6de5b1a2673e165e3f4ceb54f3c0c"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} {
  "code": -32603,
  "message": "Internal JSON-RPC error.",
  "data": {
    "code": -32000,
    "message": "Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 0 but got 2. Note that transactions can't be queued when automining.",
    "data": {
      "message": "Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 0 but got 2. Note that transactions can't be queued when automining."
    }
  },
  "stack": "{\n  \"code\": -32603,\n  \"message\": \"Internal JSON-RPC error.\",\n  \"data\": {\n    \"code\": -32000,\n    \"message\": \"Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 0 but got 2. Note that transactions can't be queued when automining.\",\n    \"data\": {\n      \"message\": \"Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 0 but got 2. Note that transactions can't be queued when automining.\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"stack\": \"Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.\\n    at new i (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:10940)\\n    at s (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:13880)\\n    at Object.internal (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:14490)\\n    at u (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:49968)\\n    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:50970\\n    at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935\"\n}\n  at new i (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:10940)\n  at s (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:13880)\n  at Object.internal (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-3.js:16:14490)\n  at u (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:49968)\n  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:7:50970\n  at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935"
} {code: -32603, message: '[ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":134079675…eogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935"\n}', stack: '{\n  "code": -32603,\n  "message": "[ethjs-rpc] rpc …hfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935'}
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
p @ inpage.js:1
f @ inpage.js:1
await in f (async)
l @ inpage.js:1
handle @ inpage.js:1
_rpcRequest @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
request @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ ethers.esm.js:19532
send @ ethers.esm.js:19578
(anonymous) @ ethers.esm.js:17752
Promise.then (async)
sendUncheckedTransaction @ ethers.esm.js:17742
sendTransaction @ ethers.esm.js:17783
(anonymous) @ ethers.esm.js:8424
fulfilled @ ethers.esm.js:8205
Promise.then (async)
step @ ethers.esm.js:8207
(anonymous) @ ethers.esm.js:8208
__awaiter$2 @ ethers.esm.js:8204
(anonymous) @ ethers.esm.js:8413
buyHandler @ Home.jsx:79
await in buyHandler (async)
callCallback2 @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Home.jsx:87 Uncaught (in promise) {code: -32603, message: '[ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":134079675…eogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935"\n}', stack: '{\n  "code": -32603,\n  "message": "[ethjs-rpc] rpc …hfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935'}
buyHandler @ Home.jsx:87
await in buyHandler (async)
callCallback2 @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
```